# Website working on Android but lookind weird on iphone

Tags: html, css

The website works fine if you use the iPhone template on the developer tool. But the measurements get messed up when you look at it on an actual iPhone for some reason.
site: https://krystletanguw.github.io/MarkTan.ca/

images:

[image: weird iphone version]

[image: normal version]

Comment: Can you post your code and an image demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of margin-bottom of `h1` in "about me" section:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 439px)
.about-heading h1 {
    font-size: 3.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```